# Webhook call from github action

Tags: github, automation, github-actions, export

I have headless cms with webhook fired whenever something change on some entities.
My question is how can i share the results of webhook(https://leon.com/api/notifyall) with other software. I read somewhere that the results can be saved as json files to github pages and then imported through the Url.

I need some guidance. Is this a good solution? Is there other pratical aproaches ?

Thanks in advance.